# Hover Over a Dragger Bar and Scroll with Selenium-Webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My code is supposed to go to a webpage, which has  a smaller scroll bar (not the larger one on the browser). On this page it needs to press a button that is originally out of view, until you hover over the bar and scroll down.

Ive seen multiple threads on how to scroll down on the whole page, but not specifically a smaller part of the page.

```
button = buttonChroPath
dragBar = draggerBarChroPath

dragBarElm = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(dragBar))
buttonElm = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(button))

hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(dragBarElm)
hover.perform()

#need to scroll here

buttonElm = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(button))
    buttonElm.click()
```

The code was edited a little and is more for reference. It works fine, but I cant find any documentation on how to hover over an element and scroll. Thank You.

Comment: are you fine using page down keyboard button ?

Comment: @Infern0 I would however page down moves the entire window down not the smaller one with the drag bar

Comment: Now trying to use this command to move the drag bar down. webdriver.ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop_by_offset(dragBarElm, dragToEleXOffset, dragToEleYOffset).perform()